# Support vector regression online learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am predicting stock prices using support vector regression. I have trained with some values but when i predict the values every time I have to train based on that(online learning). So i have passed the values to train inside the loop after predicted.

```
inside loop
 //prediction
  clf.fit(testx[i],testy[i])
```

So when i call the fit function everytime how svr training work internally **based on one input**?

Answer (score 1):

`clf.fit` is not incremental. You have to pass all the previous training points in addition to the new instance to re-train a new model that benefits from the new data points unfortunately.

This is a limitation of the SMO algorithm implemented by the libsvm library used internally in the `sklearn.svm.SVR` class.